# Using Huawei's Airsharing to stream to VLC

Tags: android, vlc-media-player, streaming, dlna

My Huawei Android phone comes with a feature called AirSharing which allows me to stream my phone's screen over DLNA. Seeing as VLC supports DLNA (I think), I installed it onto my mac, however I can't seem to get it to work. I enable multi-screen on my device and let it scan, however it doesn't see my computer and my computer doesn't see my phone. Does VLC support receiving DLNA streams? If so, what can I do?

**Note:** I couldn't find much info about AirSharing. The only documentation I found is that you need a device that supports DLNA

I am using:

- OS X 10.10.4
- Android 4.4.4 on a Huawei Ascend G7-L01
- VLC 2.2.1

Answer (score 0):

I have just recently got a honor note 8 and have been using Air share.  It seems to work when I use my phones own video app but not when using VLC.  Don't know why this is but it works really well just using the native video app.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is asking about the PC side of the connection. Does your answer imply that you use VLC on the computer? You should also at least find the name of the phone app, "phone's own video app" isn't going to help much.